# DataSnap REST server - enable HTTP KeepAlive

Tags: delphi, http, rest, keep-alive, datasnap

I'm using Delphi XE2 to build a DataSnap HTTP REST server to run as a service on Windows 2008.  I read somewhere that by default the HTTP 'KeepAlive' is disabled for DataSnap server projects, if so can somebody help as to how to enable this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Server has a property `KeepAlive`, which should be set to `true`.

Comment: Which "Server" component are you referring to? Neither the TDSServer or TDSServerClass has this property.

Comment: KeepAlive is managed at the transport layer, so the `TDSTCPServerTransport` component is a good candidate. Alternatively write a `TDSTCPServerTransport1Connect` event and call `Event.Channel.EnableKeepAlive(<some timeout>)`.